# Why query returns empty even through records are present

Tags: mysql

From User Interface , user can select a date and click on the submit button , based on the input field how to display next 30 days records ??

This is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `historical_data` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_day` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevclose_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO `historical_data` (`symbol_name`, `current_day`, `open_val`, `high_val`, `low_val`, `close_val`, `last_val`, `prevclose_val`) VALUES
('YESBANK', '01-OCT-2015', '739', '739.4', '715', '728.6', '728', '729.7').
('YESBANK', '05-OCT-2015', '732.75', '753', '732.75', '750.25', '750.95', '728.6').
('YESBANK', '06-OCT-2015', '752.4', '756.6', '736.9', '743.1', '743.25', '750.25').
('YESBANK', '07-OCT-2015', '743.1', '745.65', '733.6', '735.75', '735.15', '743.1').
('YESBANK', '08-OCT-2015', '733', '735.5', '720.45', '727.35', '725.35', '735.75').
('YESBANK', '09-OCT-2015', '733.3', '741.9', '720.1', '725.65', '725', '727.35').
('YESBANK', '12-OCT-2015', '729.3', '736.5', '720.6', '723.75', '724.1', '725.65');
```

If you see there are records from **02 OCT 2015**

But when i run the below  query

No records are being fetched

```
SELECT current_day,open_val,high_val,low_val,close_val FROM historical_data
WHERE str_to_date(current_day,'%m-%b-%Y') BETWEEN '2015-10-02' AND DATE_ADD('2015-10-02',INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND symbol_name = 'YESBANK'
```

my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6784/1

Comment: Why not store dates properly?

Comment: Perfect schema! All columns, dates, decimals, ints as varchars..

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on your `STR_TO_DATE`. Try this query

```
SELECT current_day,open_val,high_val,low_val,close_val FROM historical_data
WHERE str_to_date(current_day,'%d-%b-%Y') BETWEEN '2015-10-02' AND 
DATE_ADD('2015-10-02',INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND symbol_name = 'YESBANK'
```

or simply replace the format string `'%m-%b-%Y'` with `'%d-%b-%Y'`. The `%m` stands for the month but on your date this is the day (`%d`).

Here you can find an overview with all possible format placeholder: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

The new and working fiddle you can find here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6784/8/0